# llama_index : VectorStoreIndex

Tags: llama-index

I have the following python codes:

```
from llama_index import (
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    VectorStoreIndex,
)


documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("docs").load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)  #Why is there openAI exception thrown here? Do i need openai for this? I don't like openai API as i don't want to pay for using it.
```

Message=No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

Source=D:\MyGit\testAI\demo1\demo1.py
StackTrace:
File "D:\MyGit\testAI\demo1\demo1.py", line 14, in  (Current frame)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

I have tried the above codes and i don't understand why i need openai key!?

Answer (score 0):

Llama_index is built on OpenAI, it uses various GPT models. You can even specify which ones you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Llama-index (or in general, [RAG](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.11401)) requires two components:

1. A "retriever" which can communicate with an "index" of embeddings created earlier
2. A "response synthesizer" which will augment the responses retrieved by the earlier stage and generate a response

For both the tasks, llama-index uses OpenAI by default. You can configure several other large language models for either tasks - for the [Embedding Generation / Indexing / Retrieving](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core_modules/model_modules/embeddings/root.html), as well as for [Response Synthesis](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core_modules/model_modules/llms/root.html).

Once you move to HuggingFace / local models for both these tasks, you will no longer encounter the OpenAI error.